# Kerberos SASL authentication using node-rdkafka

Tags: node.js, docker, apache-kafka, kerberos, alpine-linux

I am having an issue trying to connect to a Kafka instance that uses Kerberos SASL authentication using the node-rdkafka npm module, and the lack of documentation and examples out there are making things very difficult to solve the issue. I am using the Alpine setup found [here](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/blob/master/examples/docker-alpine.md)
 to pull in all of the necessary librdkafka and node-rdkafka dependencies and create an image. I am trying to run my container with the following configuration object for a node-rdkafka producer to connect to Kafka instance:

```
'debug': 'all',
'client.id': 'kafka',
'metadata.broker.list': KAFKA_DOMAINS,
'sasl.kerberos.principal': '<id>@<REALM>',
'sasl.kerberos.keytab': '/path/to/<id>.keytab',
'sasl.kerberos.service.name': 'kafka',
'security.protocol': 'sasl_plaintext',
'sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd': 'kinit -kt /path/to/<id>.keytab <id>@<REALM>',
'dr_cb': true,
'event_cb': true
```

When I try to run the container, it hangs up and then throws the following error:

```
[2019-02-05T17:09:59.637Z] ERROR: kafka/7 on 95c927d11411: broker transport failure (err.code=-195)
Error: Local: Broker transport failure
    at Function.createLibrdkafkaError [as create] (/opt/rdkafka/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/error.js:261:10)
    at /opt/rdkafka/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/client.js:339:28
```

Here is the output from the features and libkafkaversion log statements:

```
[2019-02-05T17:09:29.519Z]  INFO: kafka/7 on 95c927d11411:
[ 'gzip',
  'snappy',
  'ssl',
  'sasl',
  'regex',
  'lz4',
  'sasl_gssapi',
  'sasl_plain',
  'sasl_scram',
  'plugins' ]
[2019-02-05T17:09:29.521Z]  INFO: kafka/7 on 95c927d11411: 0.11.5
```

What am I missing that I am unable to connect? Am I missing some environment variables? I know that the Java implementation of librdkafka involves passing the REALM, KDC_HOST, and some .conf files (krb5 and jaas). Do I have to set up some kind of environment variable? I can find no examples or solutions.

Comment: See this https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SASL-with-librdkafka

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. However, I have been through that document several times to no avail. Further, there are no examples connecting through Kerberos GSSAPI using node-rdkafka. I am looking to see if I have set up my configurations correctly and if I need to include some environment variable that I am missing, because I cannot get it to connect.